# Why is base class' assignment operator called?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class

In the following code I understand that the assignment operator in the struct *d* is not called on `derived1 = derived2;` and instead the default assignment operator is generated and called.
However I am confused as to why:

Why is not the explicit *d* assignment operator called on `derived1 = derived2;` when the upcasting is implicit in `b & base2  = derived1`?
**My guess** is that the default `operator=` (with header `void operator=(const derived& d)`) is always generated unless explicitly overloaded with the exact same header and will always match with an assignment made of two variables of that same type. Am I on the right path?

```
struct b {
   int x;
   void operator=(const b& base) {
      std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
   }
}

struct d: b {
   int y;
   void operator=(const b& base) {
      std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;
   }
}

int main() {
   b base1;
   d derived1;
   d derived2;
   b & base2 = derived1;

   derived1 = base1; // output: "derived"
   derived1 = derived2; // output "base"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is mostly correct. The compiler will synthesize a definition of

```
void operator=(const d&)
```

for the derived class `d`. (Unless it's not synthesized because it is explicitly `delete`d, or certain special member functions are user-defined).

This default `operator=` has the behaviour that it will do a memberwise copy of the argument, and also call the `operator=` of its base classes. In this case, that operator prints "base", and that's what you see as output.